# How can I hide NSTableview rows with backward compatibility to before OSX 10.11?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I want to hide some rows in the `NSTableView`, I implemented static cells in the `NSTableView` and I'm using them to populate it.

I already know there is `hideRows(at:withAnimation:)` but this is available only for OSX 10.11+.

I tried to set a row height to zero using `tableView(_:heightOfRow)` delegate function but this error appeared:

> Assertion failure in -[NSTableView _safeSendDelegateHeightOfRow:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1671.40.119/TableView.subproj/NSTableView.m:2166

[General] An uncaught exception was raised

> NSTableView variable rowHeight error: The value must be > 0 for row 1,
>   but the delegate 
>   gave 0.000.

`tableview.rowHeight = 0.0` fails as well

Comment: tried giving it 1px height? Also are you sure you need to hide it animated?

Comment: Yes I tried even 0.01, but there are separators. No not conditionally that withAnimation attribute can be given an empty array.

Comment: You can use `reloadData` to hide it without animation.

Comment: You would probably have to remove the items entirely to get the same effect.